# Backbone fetch: Headers are not set while performing backbone fetch with custom header data

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am developing a backbone application which involves fetching data from an external API.
My application's domain is product.site1.com whereas domain of API is api.site1.com.

This is how my model and collection looks

```
var pModel = new Backbone.Model.extend({});
var pCollection = new Backbone.Collection.extend({
                      model: pModel,
                      url: 'api.site1.com/product'
});
```

and view looks like the below

```
var pView = new Backbone.View.extend({
         initialize: function() {
                var _this = this;
                var pCollectionVar = new pCollection();
                pCollectionVar.fetch({
                           dataType: 'jsonp',
                           beforeSend: _this.sendAuthentication,
                           success: function(collection, response, options) {
                                   console.log(collection);
                           },
                           error: function(collection, xhr, options) {
                                   console.log("error");
                           }
                     });
                } 
         sendAuthentication: function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader('customKey1', 'ABCD');
            xhr.setRequestHeader('customKey2', '1234');
        }
});
```

When I execute this, my application makes a get request to the API server, whereas I am not getting the header data at the server end. I don't see these custom headers set for the request in my chrome dev tools either.

**EDIT:**
OPTIONS http://api.site1.com/product 405 (Method Not Allowed) jquery-1.10.2.js:8706

OPTIONS http://api.site1.com/product Invalid HTTP status code 405 jquery-1.10.2.js:8706

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.site1.com/product. Invalid HTTP status code 405 (index):1

These are the errors I am getting while performing the request.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use sendAuthentication like you do it should be a global function:

```
pCollectionVar.fetch({
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  beforeSend: sendAuthentication,
  success: function(collection, response, options) {
    console.log(collection);
  },
  error: function(collection, xhr, options) {
    console.log("error");
  }
});

function sendAuthentication(xhr){
   //Code goes here
}
```

Although this pollutes the global scope, I would use namespace:

```
var MyApplication = {};
MyApplication.sendAuthentication = function(xhr){ //code inside}.


pCollectionVar.fetch({
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  beforeSend: MyApplciation.sendAuthentication,
  success: function(collection, resp){//rest...}
```

**EDIT**:

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10546822/setrequestheader-does-not-work-in-jsonp-using-jquery), jsonp is not an ajax call and can't be treated as such

Comment: Okay, I understand the scoping problem here. Even after adjusting the scope, headers are not set. Will there be a problem to use jsonp along with custom headers?

Comment: @sree jsonp is not an ajax call, see Edit in answer

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.
I have included the error in the question.